# performSegue from searchDisplayController not calling prepareForSegue

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I have an `UITableView` with a custom cell that triggers a segue when selected.  No problems there.  I also have a search bar that is working fine with sorting.  The problem begins when the `searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView` is displayed, and I select a cell within that.  `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` fires without a problem.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("details", sender: self)
}
```

which then fires `performSegueWithIdentifier` without a hitch

```
override func performSegueWithIdentifier(identifier: String?, sender: AnyObject?) {
    println("Perform segue fired")
}
```

However, `prepareForSegue` is never called.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if segue.identifier == "doneSegue" {
        println("Done Segue")
    }

    if segue.identifier == "details" {
        if let destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController as? CoffeeDetailViewController {
            if let index = self.journalTable.indexPathForSelectedRow() {
                // Sets an object to hold the contents of the specific cell that was tapped
                let parametersForRow = coffeeEntry[index.row]
                let attributes: Dictionary = parametersForRow.entity.attributesByName as Dictionary
                let parameterDictionary: Dictionary = parametersForRow.dictionaryWithValuesForKeys(attributes.keys.array)
                println("Parameters: \(parametersForRow)")
                destinationVC.parameterDictionary = parameterDictionary
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have a feeling I'm making a rookie mistake and I'm just not seeing something.  Any ideas?

EDIT: I forgot a really important piece of information.  I'm using the custom cell for the `searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView` with a nib outside of storyboard.  I register the nib in `viewDidLoad`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.title = "Back"

    var nib = UINib(nibName: "CoffeeTableViewCell", bundle: nil)
    searchDisplayController?.searchResultsTableView.registerNib(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)
}
```

Comment: You have see it this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26236975/prepareforsegue-not-called-from-custom-uitableviewcell

Comment: One way I might debug this is to determine where exactly it's not performing by putting `println()` statements within the second segue call and see what's triggered. One before the `if let destinationVC = ...` and one before the `if let index = ...`. Depending on which (in any) are triggered, you'd narrow down whether or not the segue is set up properly or if the code within the block is set up properly.

Comment: I've set breakpoints throughout the prepareForSegue method.  It's never called, at all.